# Proof of existence of upper triangular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation, linear-transformations

I have a question about a step in the following proof for the existence of an upper triangular matrix for operators on a complex vector space, found in Linear Algebra Done Right, by Sheldon Axler.

[image]

It is not clear to me how the highlighted inference follows. I believe the claim is that the equation right above it shows that Tvk is in the span of (u1,…,um,v1,…,vk) for all k, as this is an equivalent condition to the existence of an upper triangular matrix. And I get why Tvk is in the span of u1,…,um, but what I don’t see is how the rest of the claim is true. For one thing, I don’t see how Tvk is in the span of vk; it seems instead to be in the span of (λk - λk)vk + Tvk, which isn’t necessarily in the span of vk because of the Tvk term. Nor do I see how Axler has shown that Tvk is in the span of the v1,…,vk-1. So if someone could help me clear things up, I’d appreciate it.

I saw there is another question on here about this exact proof, but I don’t believe it addresses this specific inference.

Comment: He never says "$Tv_k$ is in the span of $v_k$."

Answer (score 2):

As Axler notes, we have
$$
T v_k = (T - \lambda I)v_k + \lambda v_k,
$$
and $(T - \lambda I)v_k \in U$. Thus, there are scalars $c_1,\dots,c_m$  such that $(T- \lambda I)v_k  =c_1 u_1 + \cdots + c_m u_m$, which means that we can write
$$
T v_k = (T - \lambda I)v_k + \lambda v_k = (c_1 u_1 + \cdots + c_m u_m) + v_k,
$$
which is a linear combination of the vectors $u_1,\dots,u_m,v_1,\dots,v_k$ (where the coefficient of $v_j$ is $0$ for all $j < k$). So, $Tv_k$ is indeed in the span of these vectors.